# All integral solutions for $abc=100$?

Tags: combinatorics, factoring

I can't find the answer to this question anywhere: $abc=100$, find the number of integral values of $a$, $b$ and $c$.
As you might have guessed, I don't know much advanced maths so please try to explain in simple terms.
Thanks

Comment: Use the prime factorisation of $100=2^2\cdot 5^2$. You immediately find the restriction $a,b,c\in \left\{\pm 1,\pm 2, \pm 4, \pm 5,\pm 10, 
 \pm 20, \pm 25, \pm 50\right\}$.

Comment: Can be $\pm 100$ as well.

Comment: Alternatively, between them, $a, b, c$ must contain two $2$'s and two $5$'s as factors. This is now a combinatorics problem (how many ways can we distribute the $2$'s among the three variables, and how many ways can we distribute the $5$'s, and how can we distribute negative signs?)

Comment: Note that you must know if you should count permutations separately. For example is "a=100, b=c=1" and $a=b=1, c=100$ different solutions or counted as the same? What about negative numbers? For example is $a=100,b=c=1$ and $a=100,b=c=-1$ different solutions or counted as the same?

Comment: @Mathematician42 in the set of possible factors there should be also $\pm 100$

Comment: Yes, obviously, I forgot to write it down.

Comment: If you get stuck on problems that ask you to list all possibilities, it often helps to explore either a *smaller* version of the problem or on a way of organizing all the solutions in a more compact way.  For example, a smaller problem might be all the factorizations of $10$ into two integers, $AB=10$, and a way of organizing solutions might be counting only the positive integer factorizations and then all the ways that an even number of the three factors $a,b,c$ could be changed from positive to negative.

Answer (score 1):

There are no advanced maths here.

It takes little effort to guess that $a,b,c$ must be among the divisors of $100$, which are $1,2,4,5,10,20,25,50$ and $100$. You can guess them all mentally, or use a trick: once you have found the divisors until $10$, namely $1,2,4,5,10$, the remaining divisors are obtained by division: $100/5,100/4,100/1,100/1$.

Now take all combinations of two divisors and the third will follow (when possible).

$$a=1,b=1\to c=100$$
$$a=1,b=2\to c=50$$
$$a=2,b=5\to c=10$$
$$a=20,b=50\to c=-$$
$$\cdots$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are lots of different solutions.

As Mathematician 42 suggested in his answer, you should pick $a, b$ and $c$ from the set $\{\pm1, \pm2, \pm4, \pm5, \pm10, \pm 20, \pm25,\pm50, \pm100\}$

Let's find how many different solutions we have.

First notice, that $100=2^25^2$. Our divisors have to be in the form $\pm 2^k5^l$, where $k,l\in \{0,1,2\}$. Let's focus on the positive solutions.

Popular method of solving problems like this is [stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

In our case we have two types of stars - 2s and 5s.

For each group we have three places, where we can put two bars, eg. $|2|2, 5||5$ ($a=5, b=2, c=10$) or $22||,55||$ ($a=100, b=1, c=1)$.

Thus the number of different positive solutions is 
$$N=\binom{4}{2}\cdot \binom{4}{2} = 36$$

If we want to include also the negative solutions, we have to notice, that the result would be positive, if the number of negative factors is even, so we can have 0 or 2 negative factors. We can select them in $\binom{3}{0}+\binom{3}{2} = 4$ ways.

So in total there are
$$M=4\cdot 36 = 144$$
different integer solutions.

Comment: Two (identical) bars have to be placed among 3 places. You say that's $3^2$ possibilities, but shouldn't that be $6$?

Comment: Yes, you are right :) TY.

Comment: Don't you mean $N = \binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2} = 36$?